# substitution model to evaluate (f f) in sicp

Tags: scheme, sicp

I am working on Exercise 1.34 of [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-12.html#%_sec_1.3.1)

Exercise 1.34.  Suppose we define the procedure

```
(define (f g)
  (g 2))
```

Then we have

```
(f square)
4

(f (lambda (z) (* z (+ z 1))))
6
```

What happens if we (perversely) ask the interpreter to evaluate the combination `(f f)`? Explain.

Refer to the solution:

Step 1:

```
(f f)
```

Step 2:

```
(f (lambda (g)
     (g 2)))
```

Step 3:

```
((lambda (g)
    (g 2))
 (lambda (g)
    (g 2)))
```

Step 4:

```
((lambda (g)
    (g 2))
 2)
```

Step 5:

```
(2 2)
```

I got the idea of the first 3 steps, as to step 4, How could the second f be  evaluated as 2?

Other solution

The result is an error: using the substitution rule in `(f f)`

```
g = f : (g 2) -> (f 2)
```

Again using the substitution rule in `(f 2)`

```
g = 2 : (f 2)-> (2 2) -> error.
```

The actual error from DrRacket is:

The confusion remains, my mind slow to jump one step on "to be evaluated as 2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little easier to see what's going on if you define two equivalent procedures, and rename the variables to distinguish them.

```
(define (f1 g1)
  (g1 2))
(define (f2 g2)
  (g2 2))
```

And now the question is about `(f1 f2)`. Step 3 becomes:

```
((lambda (g1) ;; f1
    (g1 2))
 (lambda (g2) ;; f2
    (g2 2)))
```

When `f1` is called, `g1` is replaced with the second procedure, and it calls `(g1 2)`. So in step 4  with application model becomes:

```
((lambda (g2) ;; f2
    (g2 2))
 2)
```